# Differences between Clue/Cluedo and Clue: Discover the Secrets

Tags: cluedo

I noticed that Hasbro released a new version of Clue last year named [Clue: Discover the Secrets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0017RQYDC).

Do you need to use a different strategy in this game, or is it similar to the earlier Clue games?

I've played both the original Clue and its Master Detective variation.

I want to know because I was thinking of getting it, but wanted to know if it was different enough from the original to warrant a purchase.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but [Clue: the card game](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3269/clue-the-card-game) is another variation; it has a bit more randomness than the original game, but provides nice variation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Character changes, mostly now its a teen approach: Kasandra Scarlet, Jack Mustard, Diane White, Jacob Green, Eleanor Peacock, Victor Plum. Starting spaces have changed.

The House is now complete with Spa and Observatory inhabited by the Hollywood elite such as the bat wielding ex-football player and software billionaire fond of dumbbells. Rooms are: Hall, Guest House, Dining Room, Kitchen, Patio, Spa, Theater, Living Room, Observatory.

Characters have special powers. I.e., Kasandra Scarlet can once a game look at a card that one player has just shown another player.

Intrigue cards offer new rules. And there are some slight other changes in rules.

Purists hate it. My kids think its fun.